# ENCRYPTBYKEY produces duplicate values when a WHERE clause is used

Tags: sql-server, encryption

Below is my code:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET EncryptedCol = ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('MyKey'), '0')
WHERE MyFlag = 0x0 -- This causes every row to have the same encrypted value
```

Without the WHERE clause every row has a unique encrypted value (this is desired).  When the WHERE clause is added all of the rows being set to the encrypted value of '0' are identical.

How can I ensure a unique encrypted value for every row when using a where clause?

Comment: We're able to get unique encrypted values by pushing everything through a cursor, but it feels less than optimal.

Comment: Your supplied code should always return the same value. The second parameter of the ENCRYPTBYKEY function is the cleartext value to be encrypted, and in your code this is always '0' so should always return the same value.

Comment: I don't believe it will convert the same cleartext to the same value every time.  If you run ENCRYPTBYKEY with a cleartext value of '0' multiple times the encrypted value is different.

Comment: What version of SQL? I ran a number of tests in SQL 2017 and using '0' returned the same varbinary value from ENCRYPTBYKEY every time.